# Open a URL in a proper tab/window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to use `window.open` to open a URL in a new tab or window. At the moment I can only get it to open in a "pseudo-window" which ressembles more a pop-up than a proper window.

How can I use JavaScript to open URLs in a proper window or tab in Chrome?

Note: I've tried finding the code for the function `window.open` using the [Code Search](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search), but cannot find it.

Comment: I agree with @JezenThomas just use <a href="address" target="_blank">link</a> but if this is somehow case specific problem, then nvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is controlled by the browser and we don't have a way to change it.

You could use a hyperlink with the target set to `"_blank"` and try, but that wouldn't be `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

taken from here

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#NewTab').click(function() {
        $(this).target = "_blank";
        window.open($(this).prop('href'));
        return false;
   });
});​
```

It may help you